# How to adjust the width of edges by weight in ggraph network in r

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis, ggraph

I need to generate a network with ggraph in r.  What I want is adjust the edge width by weight variable (or the size of nodes). 
Does anyone know how I can do that? Thanks a lot.

Example code below:

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
data=data.frame(w1=rep('like', 5), 
           w2 = c('apple', 'orange', 'pear','peach', 'banana'),
           weight= c(2,3,5,8, 15))
data %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame() %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(alpha = .25) +
  geom_node_point(color = "blue", size = 2) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),  repel = TRUE)
```

Comment: i think this link might help you https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/144

Comment: @which_command that issue seems to have been solved due to conflicting packages. It was closed a year ago.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `geom_edge_link`? They list `edge_width` clearly as one of the aesthetics you can use with this geom

Comment: @camille  where is it?     geom_edge_link(mapping = NULL, data = get_edges("short"),
  position = "identity", arrow = NULL, n = 100, lineend = "butt",
  linejoin = "round", linemitre = 1, label_colour = "black",
  label_alpha = 1, label_parse = FALSE, check_overlap = FALSE,
  angle_calc = "rot", force_flip = TRUE, label_dodge = NULL,
  label_push = NULL, show.legend = NA, ...)

Comment: Geom docs generally have a heading that says "Aesthetics" that lists the accepted aesthetics, i.e. things that can be mapped to data inside an `aes` and passed to `mapping` for that geom. `geom_edge_link` is no exception to this. `edge_width` is one of those aesthetics.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this with the `width` `aes` in most `geom_edge_*`'s. Also, you can use `scale_edge_width` to finetune the min/max width according to the weighted variable. See the two examples below.

Also, I believe there was an issue with this aesthetic to do with `ggforce` (it was causing me trouble too). Make sure you've updated to the most recent versions of `ggraph` and `ggforce`.

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
data=data.frame(w1=rep('like', 5), 
                w2 = c('apple', 'orange', 'pear','peach', 'banana'),
                weight= c(2,3,5,8, 15))
```

The first with default weigthts

```
data %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame() %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(alpha = .25, 
                 aes(width = weight)) +
  geom_node_point(color = "blue", size = 2) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),  repel = TRUE)+
  theme_graph()+
  labs(title = 'Graph with weighted edges', 
       subtitle = 'No scaling')
```

[image]

Using `scale_edges_width` to set the range. 
NOTE - `scale_edges`* can take multiple arguments.

```
data %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame() %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(alpha = .25, 
                 aes(width = weight)) +
  geom_node_point(color = "blue", size = 2) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),  repel = TRUE)+
  scale_edge_width(range = c(1, 20))+ # control size
  theme_graph()+
  labs(title = 'Graph with weighted edges', 
       subtitle = 'Scaling add with scale_edge_width()')
```

[image]